# Where in source code of GRUB can I found ELF kernel loader?

Tags: elf, bootloader, grub

As we all know, GRUB can boot an ELF executable kernel. But [here](https://github.com/coreos/grub), in source code of GRUB, in which file and/or directory, the source of ELF loader resides? Also which file contains source code of Stage1 and Stage2?

Comment: https://github.com/coreos/grub/blob/2.02-coreos/grub-core/kern/elf.c

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, also if you could tell me about source code of stage1 and stage2 .

Comment: Stage1 can be found in these files: https://github.com/coreos/grub/tree/2.02-coreos/grub-core/boot/i386/pc  . A different assembyl file is sued for each type of boot method (cdrom, network boot,floppy, hard drive etc)

Comment: Thanks again for your reply, you've really helped me a lot. I also wanted to know weather STAGE2 is a simple assembly file compiled with assembler or is an elf file?